# Built-in Drupal RSS feed for front page: What tpl.php is it using?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, rss, feed, drupal-templates

Some quick testing confirms that the front-page RSS feed in Drupal 7 does not utilize the views-view-rss.tpl.php or views-view-row-rss.tpl.php.

Can you tell me which template is used by Drual for the built-in front-page RSS feed?

I am aware of the ability to create a custom RSS feed via the Views module.  I am specifically looking for information on the **front page RSS feed**, not custom feeds created in Views.

Thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: Well, of course! If you do not have views module installed, Drupal still works and which is why its independent of views-view-rss.tpl.php. Those views templates are used when you create a view and override the output and not the Drupal's default behavior!

Comment: Yes, I understand that, but everything out there in regards to documentation for changing an RSS feed refers to these two templates.  I wanted to be clear in my question that advice on how to change these templates wasn't what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a template file for that feed; it's created by the [`node_feed()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.module/function/node_feed/7) function which actually removes `#theme` from the build to make sure it doesn't go through the theme engine.

If you want to override the function altogether you can implement [`hook_menu_alter()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_menu_alter/7) in a custom module (or even a theme these days as it's an alter hook) and add a custom page callback, e.g.

```
function MYMODULE_menu_alter(&$items) {
  $items['rss.xml']['page callback'] = 'MYMODULE_node_rss';
}
```

Or you might get some mileage out of [`hook_node_view()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.api.php/function/hook_node_view/7) if you want to alter values before they're rendered to the feed:

```
function MYMODULE_node_view($node, $view_mode, $langcode) {
  if ($view_mode == 'rss') {
    // Alter $node->content in some way.
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your help.  Following your lead, I was able to locate [format_rss_item()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/format_rss_item/7) in /includes/common.inc which allowed me to make the changes I needed to make.